# Running pipelines on a dynamically growing table until all rows are processed

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a `table` that I am processing its rows through multiple pipelines.
Each of those pipelines will mark a `processed` column to true for some of the `rows` that it processes in its current run **BUT** it can also add **MORE** rows to the `table` so each run of `pipeline` could mark for example three rows as "`processed`" but also add some more rows to the table.
I want these pipelines **keep running until all rows in the table are marked as "processed"**

How can I design that part? With a `UNTIL` activity that queries the table to see if there are any on processed rows left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the total row count of the table and the count of rows where processed is true. Until they are equal, you can run the necessary pipeline activities inside the `Until` activity. The following is the demonstration of the same.

- I have a `process` pipeline which processes the rows (converts gname column to Upper case), updates processed rows to **true**, inserts new rows and puts processed value as false (All in one pipeline for demonstration).

```
#initial table data
id,gname,processed
1,'Ana','false'
2,'Ceb','false'
3,'bzm','false'

#data that will be inserted (processed will be added while inserting into table)
4,'jerax'
5,'Sumail'
```

- Now after executing pipeline **inside Until activity**, perform 2 `Script` activities where, one script activity will be used to get table row count and the other for count of rows where processed is **true**

```
#script for getRowCount
select count(*) as row_count from demo

#script for getTrueCount
select count(*) as true_count from demo where processed='true'
```

[image]

- Now, for until condition, specify the following dynamic content:

```
@equals(activity('getRowCount').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].row_count,activity('getTrueCount').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].true_count)
```

- When you run the pipeline, it runs until all the processed columns become **true** (row_count == true_count).
- Table data after 1st iteration  (until condition will be false, @equals(5,3)):

```
id,gname,processed
1,'ANA','true'
2,'CEB','true'
3,'BZM','true'
4,'jerax','false'
5,'Sumail','false'
```

- Table data after 2nd iteration (until condition will become true, @equals(5,5) and run will be completed):

```
id,gname,processed
1,'ANA','true'
2,'CEB','true'
3,'BZM','true'
4,'JERAX','true'
5,'SUMAIL','true'
```

[image]

So, you can achieve your requirement by comparing the total row count and count of processed column where its value is true (which is achieved using 2 script activities as specified above).